# In SpringBoot web service endpoint, how do I access http headers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I have a class annotated with @Endpoint and a handler method

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getWeatherRequest")
@SoapAction("http://foo/domain/getWeatherRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetWeatherResponse getWeatherRequest(@RequestPayload GetWeatherRequest request) {
    // I want to get HTTP header (Not SOAP Header) here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the @RequestHeader annotation

```
@SoapAction("http://foo/domain/getWeatherRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetWeatherResponse getWeatherRequest(@RequestPayload GetWeatherRequest request, 
@RequestHeader("header-name") String header) {
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RequestHeader` annotation in your method to access http headers, you can specify whether header is mandatory or optional using `required` attribute

```
@RequestHeader(value = "ConfigId", required = true) String configId
```